# How to return a result from Observable into a custom pipe with Angular 8?

Tags: angular, pipe, observable

I am working on an Angular 8 project and I need to return a string from a called service which return an Observable, and all this staff is into a custom pipe. Here is my code:

```
    export class ContractTypePipe implements PipeTransform {
    result;

    constructor(private referentielService: ReferentialService){}

    transform(element: number) {
      if (!element) {
        return null;
      }

      this.referentielService.getContractTypes().subscribe(res => {
        const data = res.find(ct => ct.id === element);
        this.result =  data.abbr + ' - ' + data.fr;
        return this.result;
      });
  }
}
```

and in the HTML, I use this code {{ customType | toContract }}
the problem is that the result is always blank.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Your pipe shouldn't be the one that gets the contract types from a service. That should be done by the component. Your pipe should only deal with the formatting of a contract.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by JB Nizet: 
Your pipe shouldn't be the one that gets the contract types from a service. That should be done by the component. Your pipe should only deal with the formatting of a contract

```
export class ContractTypePipe implements PipeTransform {
    result;

    constructor(private referentielService: ReferentialService){}

    transform(element: number) {
      if (!element) {
        return null;
      }

     yourmethod(): void {
      this.referentielService.getContractTypes().subscribe
     (res => this.result = res);

      }
  }
```

Your ReferentielService class should be something like:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ReferentielService {

getContractTypes(): Observable<any[]> {
  return this.http.get<any[]>(this.APIUrl)
    .pipe(
      tap(_ => this.log('fetched data')),
      catchError(this.handleError<any[]>)
    );
}
}
```